# Remove pairs of opposite values by group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have sell out data and want to remove rows/transactions when customers returned something (mat).
In these cases there is a row with a positive value and a row with a negative value in column sales. The row with the negative value has a higher date. cust and mat are the same. Both should be removed.

```
cust <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
mat <- c(123,123,123,123,123,124,123,123,124,123,125,125,130,124,124)
sales <- c(100.58,100.58,-100.58,-100.58,100.58,10,100,-100,10,100,50,-50,-1,20,20)
date <- c("2021-01-11", "2018-12-04", "2018-12-20", "2018-12-20", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-13", "2019-01-01","2019-01-02","2020-12-24","2021-01-20","2021-12-01", "2021-12-05","2013-01-01","2014-02-02","2015-03-02")
data<-data.frame(cust,mat,sales,date)
data
cust mat   sales       date
1     1 123  100.58 2021-01-11
2     1 123  100.58 2018-12-04
3     1 123 -100.58 2018-12-20
4     1 123 -100.58 2018-12-20
5     1 123  100.58 2018-12-13
6     1 124   10.00 2018-12-13
7     1 123  100.00 2019-01-01
8     1 123 -100.00 2019-01-02
9     2 124   10.00 2020-12-24
10    2 123  100.00 2021-01-20
11    3 125   50.00 2021-12-01
12    3 125  -50.00 2021-12-05
13    4 130   -1.00 2013-01-01  
14    4 124   20.00 2014-02-02
15    4 124   20.00 2015-03-02
```

This should be the result:

```
   cust mat   sales       date
   1 123  100.58 2021-01-11
   1 124   10.00 2018-12-13
   2 124   10.00 2020-12-24
   2 123  100.00 2021-01-20
   4 130   -1.00 2013-01-01
   4 124   20.00 2014-02-02
   4 124   20.00 2015-03-02
```

In the end I want the dataframe "data" having only the rows when customers keep their material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat complicated thing to do.

1. Create groups by `cust`, `mat` and the `abs`olute values of `sales`. Check if the group has more than one observation and opposite signs.
2. Create an index by the previous groups + by `sign` of `value`.
3. Group by this index + cust, mat, and the absolute value to match the pairs of opposite values. Remove those (i.e. when `n() != 1)`) and keep the rest.

You'll end up only removing pairs of opposite values.

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(cust, mat, abso = abs(sales)) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = n() > 1 & n_distinct(sign(sales)) > 1) %>% 
  group_by(grp = sign(sales), .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(cust, mat, abso, rn) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = !(replace(newcol, n() == 1, FALSE))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(newcol) %>% 
  select(-c(grp, abso, rn, newcol))

#   cust mat  sales       date
# 1    1 123 100.58 2018-12-13
# 2    1 124  10.00 2018-12-13
# 3    2 124  10.00 2020-12-24
# 4    2 123 100.00 2021-01-20
# 5    4 130  -1.00 2013-01-01
# 6    4 124  20.00 2014-02-02
# 7    4 124  20.00 2015-03-02
```

Comment: Mael, can you please check again, I added four rows (7,8,14,15). 7 and 8 should be removed. 14 and 15 should be kept.

Comment: Okay. In that case, this requires more work. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

cust <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
mat <- c(123,123,123,123,123,124,123,123,124,123,125,125,130,124,124)
sales <- c(100.58,100.58,-100.58,-100.58,100.58,10,100,-100,10,100,50,-50,-1,20,20)
date <- as.Date(c("2021-01-11", "2018-12-04", "2018-12-20", "2018-12-20", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-13", "2019-01-01","2019-01-02","2020-12-24","2021-01-20","2021-12-01", "2021-12-05","2013-01-01","2014-02-02","2015-03-02"))
data<-data.frame(cust,mat,sales,date)
setkey(setDT(data)[, abs_sales := abs(sales)], cust, mat, date)[
  , .(
    sales,
    date,
    cumdiff = cumsum(sign(sales)),
    cumrevneg = rev(cumsum(rev(sales) < 0))
  ),
  .(cust, mat, abs_sales)
][
  !(cumdiff >= 0 & cumdiff <= cumrevneg)
][
  , c(3L, 6:7) := NULL
][]
#>    cust mat  sales       date
#> 1:    1 123 100.58 2021-01-11
#> 2:    1 124  10.00 2018-12-13
#> 3:    2 123 100.00 2021-01-20
#> 4:    2 124  10.00 2020-12-24
#> 5:    4 124  20.00 2014-02-02
#> 6:    4 124  20.00 2015-03-02
#> 7:    4 130  -1.00 2013-01-01
```